# Label on a real time flot chart not showing

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, flot

Trying to add label to a real-time flot chart. chart is showing but without any label.

Original code:

```
var plot = $.plot("#placeholder", [ getRandomData() ], {
                series: {
                    shadowSize: 0,
                    lines: { show: true, fill: true}
                },
                yaxis: {
                    min: 0,
                    tickDecimals:0

                },
                xaxis: {
                    show: false
                }
            });
```

I tried this:

```
var plot = $.plot("#placeholder", [{ label: "Axis title", data: getRandomData() }], {
                series: {
                    shadowSize: 0,
                    lines: { show: true, fill: true}
                },
                yaxis: {
                    min: 0,
                    tickDecimals:0

                },
                xaxis: {
                    show: false
                }
            });
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have errors in console ?

Comment: No, no errors at all.

Answer (score 0):

Flot doesn't support axis labels (however it looks like this may be coming along in [v0.9](http://www.flotcharts.org/blog/2013/06/27/planning-for-09/)).

There is a [flot-axislabels plugin](https://github.com/markrcote/flot-axislabels) though that can be used in order to render axis labels. You will need to modify your source code to include this dependency, then you can add the following to the flot options:

```
xaxes: [{
  axisLabel: 'My Label',
}],
```

but you will have to remove the following from your original code (otherwise the x-axis will not be rendered):

```
xaxis: {
    show: false
}
```

I've created a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qveupmzv/1/) which demonstrates this. Note that this will show the x-axis ticks. If you want to remove the x-axis ticks but still show the label you can add the following option:

```
xaxis: {
  tickFormatter: function(val, axis) { return ''}
}
```

This [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qveupmzv/2/) shows the rendered chart with the x-axis label but no x-axis ticks.